# HTML Page Reload - Simulation CTRL+F5

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've my web page that use a data javascript.
All the javascript are be cached.
When I deploy a new version of my application, the user have the problem because the browser continue to use the old javascript and not the new javascript (for caching).

It's possible to simulate, when the page is loading, the *FULL* reload of all the page, including the javascript and css files (**for complete reload of the cache**)?

Thanks!!

Tommaso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following meta tag line to your header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: ? I think the solution you are suggesting is for Asp.NET :-/

Answer (score 0):

use this code in  block

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Pragma' CONTENT='no-cache'">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

or use any random number at the end of URLs.

I can see, what you can do is add a random in your JavaScript file’s reference every time. Just like the following code:

```
jsfilename.js?Math.random()
```

Then your js file cannot cache by browser.

if still not working, Follow up

http://verens.com/2008/04/09/javascript-cache-problem-solved/

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT use the meta tags suggested as they would disable the entire cache rather then clearing it for the changed files.

I recommend that you append some version unique value to the path of your files and that only change each time you deploy new changes and not just a random number that change at every page load.

Your question doesn´t tell but if you´re using ASP.NET I suggest you have a look at libraries like [SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher). It minifies your JavaScript and CSS and also appends new unique(hash) values as the files change to invalidate cached versions.